# Laravel - Strict Mode doesn't work with sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel

I'm trying to do an insert in sql server database and it returns this error:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]String or binary data would be truncated.
```

Probably Im sending data bigger than table fields but it works in mac. Now I'm setting the project to windows machine and it returns this error.

I think this is about strict mode. I know that it has to work without change length fields.

This is my connections, first mysql that works well and second sql:

```
    'mysqldb' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mysqldb'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass'),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'sqldb' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'ip'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'sqldb'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
    ],
```

Thank you

Comment: The database machine is the same? I guess you just need to set `ANSI_WARNINGS OFF`

Comment: First database is in localhos, the second is in another server @DiogoSgrillo

Comment: please show us your `insert query` and `database scheme` ... this error should mean that your `column` cannot hold your `value`